# Remove elements from numpy array by value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am analyzing a network using networkx. The networkx is stored in pandas dataframe, to create the graph I use a set of data q stored in numpy array 5053x5053, then assign the serial numbers (taken from a file stored in numpy array serials) to index and columns :

```
Import networkx as nx
Import pandas as pd

network = pd.DataFrame (data = q, index = serials, columns = serials)

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(network.values)
```

then i relabel the nodes:

```
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(enumerate(network.columns)))
```

I have a subgraph given by green products, and I have stored their serial numbers in another file imported like a numpy array (named greens). I need to have a new array to work on the two subgraph green and no green removing all the elements of green from serials.

Is there a function in numpy or should I use dicitonaries(how?)?

EDIT:
Here's a sample. Serial is a numpy array with 5053 values:

```
[ 10110  10190  10210 ... 970500 970600 999999]
```

Greens is a numpy array with 255 values:

```
[840410 840510 841410 ... 903210 460120 843680]
```

I would like to have a new array with 5053-255 values removing from serial the elements of greens.
Example:
Import numpy as np

```
a = np.array([1,5,7,9,45,52,59])
b = np.array ([1,9,52])
```

The output I would like to get is

```
c = np.array([5,7,45,59])
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html#numpy-setdiff1d) - Return the unique values in `a` that are not in `b`.

```
a = np.array([1,5,7,9,45,52,59])
b = np.array ([1,9,52])

c = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
c
array([ 5,  7, 45, 59])
```

Comment: And if order in the list matter, use `[i for i in a if i not in b]`